# Show news articles only by the year selected

Tags: 7

I am working on porting a static site over to Drupal 7, and one of the pages I am porting is a Newsroom page that starts off by listing news articles (which are internal site pages, not links to other sites) and then below that are links to different years. The way the old site works is that when a year is clicked it hides the articles that are up and then shows the articles for that year. Is there a module/plugin that can do this or is there some other way than using javascript to hide and show the different articles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a view using Views and allowing an exposed filter on the year to the user to select the year or dates.  That would then submit the request to the server and reload the page with only the selected year.  It wouldn't be pretty like using Javascript, but it would do the job.